# Python: Using run time inputs to change key values in a function

Tags: python, string, function, input

```
import sys

def fun( a=7, b=1 ):
    print a, b

fun()
fun( a=5 )
fun( sys.argv[1:] )
```

The first fun() prints out '7,1', the second prints out '5,1', but the third prints out '['a=8', 'b=6'] 1]'. I would like to be able to call my program with

```
python my_program.py a=5 b=6
```

to change the value of the printed a and b. But this doesn't work since sys.argv[1] is a list of strings.

Is there any way to convert the the string list to a form the function can understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `**` for kwarg unpacking:

```
d = {}
for a in sys.argv[1:]:
    k, v = a.split('=')
    d[k] = int(v)
func(**d)
```

Another way, using the `csv` module:

```
import csv
func(**{k: int(v) for k, v in csv.reader(sys.argv[1:], delimiter='=')})
```

As @MartijnPieters noted you may use the `argparse` module

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('-a', type=int)
parser.add_argument('-b', type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()
fun(**dict(args._get_kwargs()))
```

but then you have to adjust the way you input your arguments

Comment: Oh damn, 5 second difference

Comment: @Haidro See what happens next. I bet the top answer will be Martijn's anyway

Comment: This now prints out 'a=5,b=6', not '5,6'.
It is essentially setting a = 'a=5', b = 'b=6'.
Is there a way to get the function to treat them as keywords?

Answer (score 4):

Use `*` to unpack a list into arguments:

```
fun(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Note that this will result in *string* arguments; `sys.argv` command line entries are always strings.

You may want to look into the [`argparse` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) to handle command line arguments for you, including automatic conversion:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('-a', type=int, default=7)
parser.add_argument('-b', type=int, default=1)
args = parser.parse_args()

func(args.a, args.b)
```

Then use:

```
$ python my_program.py -a=5 -b=6
```

The added advantage here is that you get proper help feedback, *and* you follow standard command-line conventions:

```
$ python my_program.py --help
usage: [-h] [-a A] [-b B]

Process some integers.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -a A
  -b B
```